# Recursive referencing the same class

Tags: json, class, rest, recursion, servicestack

In my case I stared to use ServiceStack...

I created a class

```
public class dtoClass
{
    public string aText { get; set; }
    public DbGeography dbGeo { get; set; }
    public dtoClass d { get; set; }
}
```

on the output of servicestack via rest -->

I get this

```
{"aText":"String","d":{"aText":"String","d":{"aText":"String","d":{"aText":"String"}}}}
```

You will see it ends on the 3 level in referencing dtoClass d

My question is, how do I specify that this happens 8 levels inward ? Rather than just 3 ?

Comment: I would double check your data. I tested something 5 levels deep and it works fine.

Comment: Did you add any attributes... in my cases it stop on 3 levels deep. Or is it a setting somewhere to allow it go a certain amount of levels deep ?

Comment: There are no attributes or settings. It will go as deep as the data you provide. Make sure you make the props public like mythz suggested. You might want to try hard coding your data and creating a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note Pretty much all of [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/)'s POCO support only works with **public properties**. i.e. change your class to:

```
public class dtoClass
{
   public String aText {get;set;}
   public dtoClass d {get;set}
}
```